# XCode 6 GM eating disk space and memory

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to update our iPhone app to work with iOS 8 but when I build with XCode 6 it'll freeze on compiling the storyboard and start eating disk space and memory - this happens sporadically.

So it'll build fine on one simulator or phone a few times and then I'll try and build again and it just freezes (always on compiling storyboard step). Then I check and there are Gigabytes of disk space missing and then the computer will crash once all memory is gone too.

I'm stumped here and can't release our app to work with iOS 8 because XCode 6 isn't working!

It's like sometimes the storyboard compilation is causing a huge memory leak (but also disk space which is weird).

I'm on the GM version of XCode 6. I've also tried XCode 6.1 beta.

XCode 5 works fine.

Would love any ideas! Really stuck here.

You can see Interface Builder is eating the memory:
[image: It's definitely Interface Builder that's eating the memory]

Comment: I am having the exact some problem! Did you find any workaround?

Comment: No. I ended up going back to XCode 5. Apple is allowing submissions with XCode 5 again. If I want to test on an iOS 8 device then I open XCode 6 and get it to recognize the device, then open XCode 5 and I can then compile to the device.

Comment: +1.same problem with me, freeze on compiling the storyboard. waiting for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you created your project in Xcode 5, Auto Layout was turned ON by default. There is a major bug in Xcode 6.0 (hopefully one that Apple is addressing) with Auto Layout and projects created in Xcode 5. Here's what you need to do:

Open your project (or workspace) and RIGHT click on the storyboard file(s). Select Open As -> Source Code. Look toward the top of the XML text document. You should see autoLayout="ON". Simply remove this text. Now CLEAN and BUILD. You should be able to run your project with no problems.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I only see this text: useAutolayout="YES". When I tried removing it the storyboard crashes.

Comment: Well it worked perfectly for me. Haven't had any issues since I removed that bit of code from the IB source code. This may be because I am NOT actually using auto layout - my apps are for portrait up orientation only. If you are using constraints and auto layout that may be a different matter. Good luck!!